# Can't upload JSON files in Parse Data Browser

Tags: ios, json, parse-platform

I'm having trouble uploading a JSON file in the "File column" of the Data Browser

Actually this one gets uploaded

```
"foo" : [{ "bar": "test", "haha" : "lol" }]

But this can't be uploaded

{ "foo" : [{

 "bar": "test",
 "haha" : "lol"
}] }
```

I need the second one because that format is the valid JSON format and gets parsed with `AFNetworking`'s JSON parser.

I'm having this error if I use the first JSON format

```
Error: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 3840.)" (JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.) UserInfo=0x10d4301b0 {NSDebugDescription=JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set.}
```

EDITED: Here's the code requested

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
    [manager GET:@"the link link to the JSON file" parameters:nil success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

    //Do things here with the responseObject

    } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);

    }];
```

I'm actually trying to host the JSON file in Parse by uploading it to a File Object in the Data Browser. Then I'm going to get it with AFNetworking. From my observation a JSON file with valid structure does not get uploaded

Comment: I use parse, but am not sure what you mean by the File column.  Not sure either what you mean by uploading a JSON file.  Maybe it doesn't matter... why not just strip off the outer curlys from the AFNetworkingResult before sending to parse?

Comment: can you please explain with some code snippet that you are trying..

Comment: @danh Actually what I meant by the File Column is a column in the Parse Data Browser with a data type of "File". I'm uploading a JSON file. I'm not importing it to create a Parse class. I'm actually trying to host the JSON file in Parse and later get it with AFNetworking

Answer (score 0):

Without the code it is really difficult to comment. However, the times I've encountered Cocoa 3840 error were because my JSON structure was incorrect.

This will sound childish, but here it goes:

[] means array {} means dictionary.

I guess, the key "foo" relates to an array. When the foo is contained within {} I think foo is declared within a NSDictionary; the coding should be like

```
NSMutableArray *local_array = @[@{@"bar":@"test",@"haha":@"lol"}]
NSDictionary *dict = @{@"foo":local_array};
```

Try the NSJSONSerialization over this dictionary and see if any error occurs

Comment: Please see edited post. From what I've observed a JSON file with a valid structure (checked it with jsonlint.com) does not get uploaded in the Parse Data browser's File Object

Comment: Have you fired the file path on the browser normally and see if the file exists?

Comment: The file does not get uploaded. There is no confirmation or whatsoever. I tried other file other types and I get a confirmation of having successfully uploaded the object